# how to format the text-file data to a specific standard JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have data in a text file (test.txt), as below format

```
ABCD=123=Durham
EFGH=456=Nottingham
IJKL=789=Peterborough
```

I want to convert it to a standard json/dictionary (list of items) as below

```
{
"data":[
         {
         "name":"ABCD",
         "id":"123",
         "place":"Durham",
         },

         {
         "name":"EFGH",
         "id":"456",
         "place":"Nottingham",
         },

         {
         "name":"IJKL",
         "id":"789",
         "place":"Peterborough",
         },
]
}
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: You need to include more info about the layout of the file. 
Will it always be 4 chars, equals, 3 digits, equals, one word?
Is there a chance for equals symbols elsewhere and if so, are they escaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
input='''ABCD=123=Durham
EFGH=456=Nottingham
IJKL=789=Peterborough'''
print(json.dumps({'data': [dict(zip(('name', 'id', 'place'), l.split('='))) for l in input.split('\n')]}))
```

This outputs:

```
{"data": [{"name": "ABCD", "id": "123", "place": "Durham"}, {"name": "EFGH", "id": "456", "place": "Nottingham"}, {"name": "IJKL", "id": "789", "place": "Peterborough"}]}
```

Comment: i tried zipping, it worked. Can i create multi-level/nested dictionary ? say, like {"data": "ABCD":{"id":"1234","place":"Durham"},"EFGH":{"id":"456","place":"Nottingham"}}

Comment: This will do: `print(json.dumps({'data': {k: dict(zip(('id', 'place'), v.split('='))) for k, v in dict((l.split('=', 1) for l in input.split('\n'))).items()}}))`

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps

```
import os
import json

row_keys = ["name","id","place"]

data_dict = {"data":[]}

with open("test.txt", "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        row_values = line.split("=")
        row_values[2] = row_values[2].replace(os.linesep, '')
        row_dict = dict(zip(row_keys, row_values))
        data_dict["data"].append(row_dict)
        # print (data_dict)
        # print (row_dict)
json_output = json.dumps(data_dict, ensure_ascii=False)
print (json_output)
```